# What is the appropriate method for requesting the removal of a bad-answer banner?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63938/1629) has the "citation needed" banner and I think it doesn't need it. (There's a link to a Verge article that has all the relevant information and even a quote from Verizon.)

What is the proper procedure for requesting the banner's removal? In the past I've flagged the answer, but I don't want to spam the flag queue.

Comment: Also, this question was a dupe. And the original doesn't have an answer. Whoops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators control notices so you could post a link in the chat room, pinging us or simply by flagging the post.

Meta questions also alert us - but in your case - documenting this on meta is awesome. Thanks for the flag and the question. Our flag volume is manageable and this is a good use of the system, even if we were backed up with many to handle.

Comment: So flagging is acceptable? And how do I pick which one of you to flag? Should I try to rotate between mods?

Comment: The flagging system is a simple queue. When we log into the site - we have a status that is visible to let us know the flag count. You don't get to direct things and it's simply a pick and process where we can see all the flags and take whatever ones we feel we can decide at that moment.

Comment: I meant "how do I pick which one of you to *ping*"; sorry.

Comment: You can't ping one of us as a flagging event. In chat it's easier as @bmike or @ whatever.